# How do I use spatial index to speed up a model?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, spatial-index

I want to process data with a model in QGIS. It works fine, but the bigger the datasets get, the longer it takes. The reason is, I use GeoJSON layers and they don't have a spatial index. That is why I exported the GeoJSON layers to Geopackage format before I used them in the model. When I go to properties in the geopackage layers in the layer panels it says "spatial index exists":

[image]

But when I run the model, it says that the input layers (geopackage format) don't have spatial indixes. I don't understand why:

[image]

How can I make sure, that the model uses Spatial Indexes to speed up geoprocessing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you have to recreate the index after each geoprocessing tool in your model. I usually insert "Create Spatial index" multiple times in my models, every time I get the warning. But maybe there's some setting to automatically create them

Comment: @BERA: Thats interesting, I didn't know that. It would be great to have a general option for including spatial indexes in all geoprocessing steps in the model.